# Frontcontroller plugin does not load

Tags: zend-framework, plugins, front-controller

When i use a frontcontroller plugin in zend frameworker it seems to run before the autoloader. How should i do this?

in my app.ini

```
resources.frontController.plugins.routes = "Plugin_Routes"
```

plugins/Routes.php

```
class Plugin_Routes extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {
}
```

The error message..

Fatal error: Class 'Plugin_Routes' not found in /usr/share/php/Zend/Application/Resource/Frontcontroller.php on line 111

No include path at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to have :

```
resources.frontController.plugins[] = "Dagho_Controller_Plugin_Auth"
```

and its working for me very nice

**update** : nothing to fancy just these lines below and doctrine autoloader

```
protected function _initAutoload() {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
                    'namespace' => 'Default',
                    'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__),
                ));

        return $autoloader;
    }
```

Comment: Same effect.. I think it is the same except you dont have an associatvive array and a extra namespace. Do you have something in the bootstrap to load the autoloader at first ?

Comment: oh , could you please double check the permission !

Comment: Ok you got me in the right direction :D Seems the namespace is forced on plugins... even the manual does not mention this :)

Answer (score 1):

Is that right?

```
plugins/Routes.php
```

Zend expects

```
Plugin/Routes.php
```

Because the autoloader will use the class name to find the right folders.

```
My_Class_Something
```

Will be:

```
My/Class/Something.php
```

Comment: But this is the directory Zend tool makes... same as modules / and controllers / are lower case and plural but in your class name you make them with a capital and singular

In the error message there is not even an include path, which makes me think that the autoloader does not exists yet before registering plugins.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing works, try to play with the autoloader.

add this code in the bootstrap class

```
protected function _initBlablablaPlugin(){

    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    //If your plugin is placed in the /library/My/Plugin/Blablabla, then register the "My_" namespace
    $autoloader->registerNamespace('My_');

    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $frontController->registerPlugin(new My_Plugin_Authorize());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok the manual seems to be wrong or atleast not clear:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.controller.plugins.html

What is missing is you need the application namespace else it will not work in 1.11

app.ini

```
resources.frontController.plugins.routes = "Application_Plugin_Routes"
```

plugin

```
class Application_Plugin_Routes extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract { }
```

Will work ok :)